# Subnet address in apache access log

Tags: apache-2.2, networking

I was inspecting my apache access logs(I use default combined log format) and I came a cross a  wired entry

```
69.171.247.0 - - [22/Oct/2012:18:15:20 +0200] "GET /some site resources HTTP/1.1" 404 514 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.0 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"
```

As u see, this query come from a facebook robot that extract objects from site when somebody post a link.
What I find weird is the logged ip address : 69.171.247.0

Does anybody know how is that possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a perfectly valid host IP address.

As you can see from a whois query on that address, it's part of a `/19` subnet allocated to Facebook. They can subnet that allocation however they choose.

Thinking in terms of a "standard" `/24` network, the .0 address would not be a host address, but it's perfectly valid in subnets larger than `/24`.

Please see [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-ipv4-subnetting-work) for an exhaustive explanation of subnetting in the IPv4 world.

Comment: Unless my logic is off, a x.x.x.0 host address would only be valid in a network of /23 or larger.

Comment: @USDMatt - yes, that's correct. I've clarified my answer.